# HTML5 video tags not working

Tags: html, video

I am trying to make a website where I have multiple videos on it. When I run the code, only the first video loads. No matter what I do, the second video will not play or load. Why doesn't my second video load?

Here's my code:

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Andrew soundboard!</title> 
<style>
h1{
text-align:center;
}
</style>
</head> 
<body>
<h1>Andrew Soundboard!</h1> 
<br>
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls" autobuffer> 
<source src="IMG_3558.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<object data="" width="320" height="240"> 
<embed width="320" height="240" src="IMG_3558.mp4"> 
</object> 
</video> 
<br>
FREAK OUT #1

<br><br>

<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls" autobuffer> 
<source src="IMG_3559.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<object data="" width="320" height="240"> 
<embed width="320" height="240" src="IMG_3559.mp4"> 
</object> 
</video> 
<br>
STOP IT!

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure your video is on your server and named exactly as in your code? ("IMG_3559.mp4")

Comment: I've no problem with your code http://codepen.io/tuga/pen/PNaLRM , make sure the second video exists and it's correctly encoded.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your code.  So the possible issues are:

1. Is your video on your server (or if running on computer, in an accessible folder)?
2. Are you linking to your video correctly (in the right file, etc.)?
3. Does your video have the exact same file name as your HTML?
4. Does your video have the EXACT same file extension as your HTML? (.mp4, .mov, etc.)

Hope this helped!